# How to find polygons that partly is contained in a bigger polygon with solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, spatial-query

I have a structure with polygons that describes countries, states, cities, and city districts.

If I select a district, I use that polygon to get parents of that district:

"Brooklyn": "New York City", "New York State", "USA"

I use "Contains()" for this, and most times it works great. However, at some times a city-polygon goes a bit outside of the parent, its no longer returned (which is how its supposed to be). My question is, how can I return these objects?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an relational graph to organise your districts / polygons?
This way you are not bound the the physical representation/location/surface.

USA -> New York State -> New York City -> Brooklyn

USA -> New York State -> New York City -> Queens

Comment: I did, however this creates a big problem when areas are changed or added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Intersects()` for that use case. It should be documented along with `Contains()`, so refer to your Solr exact versions doc and you should be good to go.

Comment: Be aware that this will also get the children of the object, so you'll have to calculate the area as well to know which are the parents and which are the children.

Comment: Yes, as MatsLindh says this will also include children. Do you have any ideas about how to exclude those?

Comment: so, how is that different from your current approach, does not a query that Contains(brooklyn) return NYState and USA too?

Answer (score 0):

A parent is a polygon where the area of (child - parent) equals 0 and the area of (parent - child) equals (area of parent - area of child), you could rank polygons by the deviation from those equalities (or another similarly formed one) and allow a user to choose a threshold.